# Synced reading from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, synchronization

I have a value I need to read from Firebase and then write it together with multiple other values to Firebase in a transaction of two objects total.

I am creating a CHAT and so when a message is sent, I am creating a chat room for both contacts, each to his own. My code :

```
private func CreateChatRoom(creatorID: String, creatorName: String ,contactID: String, contactName: String)
    {

        var creatorImageString: String = ""
        var contactImageString: String = ""
        ReadContactImage(contactID: contactID)
        {
            success in

            if success
            {
                contactImageString = self.tempContactImg
            }
        }
        ReadContactImage(contactID: creatorID)
        {
            success in

            if success
            {
                creatorImageString = self.tempContactImg
            }
        }

        let infoForCreator = [Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_NAME: contactName,
                              Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_ID: contactID,
                              Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS : 0,
                              Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_IMG_URL: contactImageString] as [String : Any]


        let infoForContact = [Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_NAME: creatorName,
                              Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_ID: creatorID,
                              Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS : 0,
                              Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_IMG_URL: creatorImageString] as [String : Any]

        let childUpdates = ["\(creatorID)/\(contactID)/": infoForCreator,
                            "\(contactID)/\(creatorID)/": infoForContact
                           ]

        Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
    }

    private func ReadContactImage(contactID: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ())
    {
        Constants.refs.databaseUsers.child(contactID).child(Constants.Account.AccountFields.USER_IMAGE_STR).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            self.tempContactImg = (snapshot.value as? String)!
            completion(true)
        })
    }

    var tempContactImg : String = "";
```

I read here on SO that the function "ReadContactImage" should run synchronously, but it does not. So I'm left with empty contact images.

I thought about just reading both images in the same function, but `CreateChatRoom` also needs to be synchronous, so I am left with the same problem, basically.

Does anyone know how to handle this properly ?

Is there maybe an easier way of doing this?

Edit:

If writing to Database is async, I get an exception here:

```
func AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: NSDictionary!)
    {
        if chatAsDictionary == nil
        {
            return
        }
        let contactName = chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_NAME] as! String
        let contactImg = chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_IMG_URL] as! String
        //let lastMsg = chatAsDictionary["lastMessage"] as! String
        let newMsgs = chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS] as! Int
        let contactID = chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_ID] as! String

        let chatToAdd = PrivateChatLiteObject(chattingWith: contactName, ContactID: contactID, unreadMessages: newMsgs, LastMSG: "", ContactImageStr: contactImg)


        chatsDictionary[contactID] = chatToAdd
        chatsIndex.append(contactID)
    }
```

When trying to use the information in dictionary, which is taken from Firebase.
That function is called from here:

```
private func populateActiveChats()
    {
        let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(loggedOnUserID!)

        // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
        ref.observe(.value, with:
                { (snapshot) in

                    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    {

                        if (self.chatsDictionary.keys.contains(child.key) == false)
                        {
                            let chatValueDictionary = child.value as? NSDictionary
                            self.AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: chatValueDictionary)
                            self.DispatchQueueFunc()
                        }


                    }
            })
    }
```

Which is called from `viewDidLoad()` when I open my Chats page.

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Because chatAsDictionary[CONTACT_NAME] doesn't exist, because when chatAsDictionary gets its data from Firebase, it is not yet written there from the async function

Comment: "I get an exception" -> Always provide complete error details: the exact message and stack trace. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: It is a null exception since chatDictionary[CONTACT_NAME] isn't initialized because it was not yet written to Firebase at time of extraction

Answer (score 0):

Both methods you call load data from Firebase asynchronously. You can't constructor `infoForCreator` (et al) until both calls to `ReadContactImage` have completed.

A simple way to do that is to nest the calls:

```
var creatorImageString: String = ""
var contactImageString: String = ""
ReadContactImage(contactID: contactID)
{
    success in

    if success
    {
        contactImageString = self.tempContactImg
        ReadContactImage(contactID: creatorID)
        {
            success in

            if success
            {
                creatorImageString = self.tempContactImg

                let infoForCreator = [Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_NAME: contactName,
                      Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_ID: contactID,
                      Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS : 0,
                      Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_IMG_URL: contactImageString] as [String : Any]


let infoForContact = [Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_NAME: creatorName,
                      Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_ID: creatorID,
                      Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS : 0,
                      Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_IMG_URL: creatorImageString] as [String : Any]

let childUpdates = ["\(creatorID)/\(contactID)/": infoForCreator,
                    "\(contactID)/\(creatorID)/": infoForContact
                   ]

                   Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative, you can keep a counter:

```
var creatorImageString: String = ""
var contactImageString: String = ""
var completedCount = 0;
ReadContactImage(contactID: contactID)
{
    success in

    if success
    {
        contactImageString = self.tempContactImg
        completedCount++
        if completedCount == 2
        {
            createDatabaseNode(contactImageString, creatorImageString)
        }
    }
}
ReadContactImage(contactID: creatorID)
{
    success in

    if success
    {
        creatorImageString = self.tempContactImg
        completedCount++
        if completedCount == 2
        {
            createDatabaseNode(contactImageString, creatorImageString)
        }
    }
}
```

And `createDatabaseNode` is then a function that contains your code to populates the data structures and calls `updateChildValues`.

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction, but now I am getting an exception somewhere else, because some information is not written to Database when I use it. I'll add code soon

Comment: Added "Edit" section to my post

Comment: Added what you asked for